# Name for a flat version of a grappling hook?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I was working with a group of students yesterday in a writing class.

One of them wrote a story involving a hero, a damsel, and a tower (a riff on the Rapunzel theme).
To get up to the top of the tower, the student had the hero attach a rope to his sword and fling it up to the top, where it lodged behind the battlements, securing the end of the rope, allowing him to scale the walls - the process was clear, and we could all visualise it.

However, we were all stumped when trying to think of a better way of describing this than using the simile of a grappling hook and were keen to use a more specific term.

Is there a specific name for a tool such as this?

Comment: Perhaps, it can be called a _makeshift grappling hook_.

Comment: The original [*toggle*](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+toggle&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS724US727&oq=define+toggle&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512l6j0i390l3.8845j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: Someone else can make an answer of it, I'm off to work. Throwing swords straight up doesn't bode well for a long life.

Comment: Various descriptions such as variations of *hooking a rope up*, *throwing/tossing a rope*, but no formal name.

Comment: @Phil's answer is technically as sound as it gets, but the ideas of using a sword as a toggle or a lengthy toggle in place of a grappling hook do sound improbable.

Comment: The point is that the sword did not function as a grappling hook that uses penetration to secure it. The sword would jam between the crenellations of the battlements, not penetrate them. -- To me "toggle" although technically and etymologically correct, is a word that did not enter the language until the mid-18th century and sounds a little weak for this heroic act.

Comment: How does an improvised tool have its own distinct name?

Comment: Tying a rope around a sword doesn't bode too well for the climber either. If it is going to work as a toggle secured by a battlement it will need to be round the centre of the blade... the sharp part.

Comment: @WeatherVane - The sword could have still been housed in its scabbard. The rope could have been protected against fraying by powerful magic. This ain't historical realism we're aiming for here - in the realm of story, everything is possible.

Comment: I think readers would understand 'grappling hook' more readily than 'toggle'. *... a makeshift grappling hook.*

Comment: You could call it a *grapple*, which *is* a hook, but it de-emphasizes the barb (or lack of barb) aspect.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Or "grapnel", which shares the virtues you mention.

Answer (score 1):

Some Ideas to consider :

[holdfast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holdfast_(tool))
"A holdfast or hold fast is a form of temporary clamp used to hold a workpiece firmly to the top or side of a wooden workbench or the top of an anvil."

[roof anchor](https://www.grainger.com/category/safety/fall-protection/anchorage-connectors/roof-anchors)
"Roof anchors create an anchoring point to secure a connecting device such as a lanyard or SRL when working at height."

The hero tied a rope to his Worthy Sword & threw it over the tower battlements. When he pulled the rope back , the Sword formed a **holdfast OR roof anchor** by lodging between two frames on the crenellation. The taut rope was enough to climb onto the roof & retrieve his Worthy Sword. He then took a moment to look around & contemplate his next move.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of a thing that is attached to a rope and thrown upwards and lodges behind something where it sticks and allows someone to climb the rope is **exactly** described by the word "grappling hook". The term can describe the usage as well as the thing. So:

> He used his sword as a grappling hook and climbed up the rope.

is perfectly fine. If he had an actual grappling hook but no sword you could say instead:

> He used his grappling hook as a sword and cut down his enemies with it